# Android GSON error :Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NAME at line 1 column 61

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My Json String is look like this:

```
{
    "Status": "Success",
    "ErrorText": "",
    "GetMySizeResult": {
        "Chest": "43",
        "Shoulder": "33",
        "NeckFront": "32",
        "NeckBack": "2",
        "Waist": "3",
        "Abdomen": "3",
        "Hip": "4",
        "Length": "4",
        "SlitLength": "4",
        "ArmHole": "4",
        "SleeveLengthShort": "4",
        "SleeveLengthLong": "4",
        "SleeveRoundShort": "",
        "SleeveRoundLong": "",
        "WaistToAnkle": "",
        "Thigh": "",
        "Knee": "",
        "Calf": "",
        "Ankle": "",
        "Instruction": "",
        "Note": ""
    }
}
```

My coding is below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T JsonParseforReturnModel(T t, String response)
            throws JsonSyntaxException, IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
        JsonReader reader;
        reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        reader.beginObject();
        reader.nextName();
        reader.nextString();
        reader.nextName();
        reader.nextString();
        reader.nextName();
        reader.beginObject();
        t = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, t.getClass());

        reader.close();
        return t;
    }
```

but it contains error:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NAME at line 1 column 61
```

please solve my error.Thanks in advance.sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove `reader.beginObject()` before calling `gson.fromJson()`. It looks `gson.fromJson()` expects begin_object tag but it has being already consumed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't necessarily the answer your looking for, but I find that the easiest and most maintainable way to use Gson is to define a class for the object, then use gson to unpack to that class.

i.e.

```
public class PersonSizesMessage{
  public String status;
  public String error;
  public PersonSizes personSizes;
}

public class PersonSizes{
  int Chest;
  int Shoulder;
  // and all the rest...
}

PersonSizesMessage msg = gson.fromJson(jsonString, PersonSizesMessage.class);
```

See the "BagOfPrimitives" example in the [docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).